# Storing byte arrays in a SecureString fails sporadically

Tags: c#, .net, security, extension-methods, securestring

Before somebody comes up with the "why would you do that" be contempt with the fact that I need that. If not, then I simply want a secure byte array, think of it as a binary passphrase. Now on to the stuff!

I have the following extension method to get a SecureString instance from data in a byte array:

```
public static SecureString FromByteArray(this SecureString secure, byte[] data)
{
    secure.Clear(); // throw exception if IsReadOnly
    char[] chars = new char[data.Length];

    chars = data.Select(c => (char)c).ToArray();
    foreach (char c in chars)
    {
        secure.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return secure;
}
```

Then somewhere in StackOverflow I found the following that dumps a SecureString to a byte[]:

```
public static byte[] ToInsecureBytes(this SecureString securePassword)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;

        if (null != securePassword)
        {
            GCHandle? gc = null;
            var handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            var length = securePassword.Length;

            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
            try
            {
                handle = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi(securePassword);
                bytes = new byte[length];
                gc = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    bytes[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(handle, i);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocAnsi(handle);
                }

                if (null != gc &&
                    gc.HasValue)
                {
                    gc.Value.Free();
                }
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

Do notice that the code is independent of string encoding because we are considering the data as a mere binary but using the SecureString features.

Then I have this test code in LinqPad to prove the concept:

```
byte[] byteData = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();  // byte[32]
BitConverter.ToString(byteData).Dump();

SecureString pwd4 = pass.FromByteArray(byteData);
byte[] byteOut = pwd4.ToInsecureBytes();
BitConverter.ToString(byteOut).Dump();
Console.WriteLine("Conversion successful: {0}", byteData.SequenceEqual(byteOut));
```

But when run as round trip conversion I notice that they are not the same, always there is a  mismatch in the sequence and it is always a character with hex code 0x3F which appears mysteriously in random places of the byteOut array.

```
07-F7-90-67-A7-46-1E-F9-CE-44-91-46-44-9D-B9-81-75-7B-27-43-34-C3-F9-38-AC-E7-F9-E6-F1-7F-29-84
07-F7-90-67-A7-46-1E-F9-CE-44-3F-46-44-9D-B9-81-75-7B-27-43-34-C3-F9-38-AC-E7-F9-E6-F1-7F-29-3F
Conversion successful: False
```

Comment: You cannot store a byte[] in a string, not without encoding it.  Not every possible byte value has a corresponding Unicode character.  It does sound like you don't understand why SecureString exists, it is necessary because System.String is immutable.  That is not a problem with byte[], you can trivially pin and scrub it.

Comment: In .NET, `string`, `char` and `SecureString` are not independent of encoding; Their encoding is always UTF-16.